# Complex Select and Input Text Filed Combo with add more and remove option

Tags: reactjs

I have a drop down also a text filed. User can select which kind of link they are providing and then give link in input text.
Also they can add more links of different kind. Only 1 link of 1 kind.
If they made mistake they can remove any link.

I am stuck in this problem and unable to figure out any simple solution.

Final output required is an array projectLinks. [{web:"url"},{android:"url"}]

Please help.

[image: Output Needed]
React Code:

```
import MainLayout from "./layouts/MainLayout";

const linkOptions = [
  { value: "web", label: "Web" },
  { value: "android", label: "Android" },
  { value: "ios", label: "iOS" },
  { value: "youtube", label: "Youtube" },
  { value: "twitter", label: "Twitter" }
];

type ProjectLinks = [
  { web?: string },
  { android?: string },
  { ios?: string },
  { youtube?: string },
  { twitter?: string }
];

export default function App() {
  const [projectLinks, setProjectLinks] = useState<ProjectLinks>();
  const [numberOfLinks, setNumberOfLinks] = useState(1);
  const handleChangeOption = (event: any) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };
  const submit = () => {
    console.log("Submitted");
  };
  const handleAddLink = () => {
    setNumberOfLinks((prev) => prev + 1);
  };
  const handleRemoveLink = () => {
    setNumberOfLinks((prev) => prev - 1);
  };
  return (
    <MainLayout>
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        {[...Array(numberOfLinks)].map((_, index) => (
          <LinkField
            key={index}
            handleChangeOption={handleChangeOption}
            handleAddLink={handleAddLink}
            handleRemoveLink={handleRemoveLink}
          />
        ))}
        <button className="btn btn-active mt-8" onClick={submit}>
          Button
        </button>
      </div>
    </MainLayout>
  );
}

function LinkField({
  handleChangeOption,
  handleAddLink,
  handleRemoveLink
}: {
  handleChangeOption: (event: any) => void;
  handleAddLink: () => void;
  handleRemoveLink: () => void;
}) {
  return (
    <div className="mt-1 mb-1">
      <div className="flex justify-between">
        <select onChange={handleChangeOption} className="select select-primary">
          {linkOptions.map((option, index) => (
            <option key={index} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="example.com"
          className="input input-bordered ml-1 mr-1"
        />
        <button
          className="btn btn-md btn-active ml-1 mr-1"
          onClick={handleAddLink}
        >
          Add
        </button>
        <button
          className="btn btn-md btn-active ml-1 mr-1"
          onClick={handleRemoveLink}
        >
          Remove
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am using tailwindcss with daisyui.

Comment: Data needs to be saved in state when choosing item from drop-down and on blur/change of input field, and on button(add) click can save data as key value pair and push it in an array

Comment: Are you restricting setProjectLincks for 5 items? Because this line can this issue - > useState<ProjectLinks>()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by avoiding most of the state variables and used form submit.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import MainLayout from "./layouts/MainLayout";

const linkOptions = [
  { value: "web", label: "Web" },
  { value: "android", label: "Android" },
  { value: "ios", label: "iOS" },
  { value: "youtube", label: "Youtube" },
  { value: "twitter", label: "Twitter" }
];

type ProjectLinks = [
  { web?: string },
  { android?: string },
  { ios?: string },
  { youtube?: string },
  { twitter?: string }
];

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const [urlError, setUrlError] = useState(false);
  const submit = (event: any) => {
    let urlTypeArray: string[] = [];
    let urlArray: string[] = [];
    let projectLinks: ProjectLinks[] = [];
    [...Array(count)].map((_, index) => {
      let url =
        count === 1 ? event.target.url.value : event.target.url[index].value;
      let urlType =
        count === 1
          ? event.target.urlType.value
          : event.target.urlType[index].value;
      if (
        urlTypeArray.includes(urlType) ||
        urlArray.includes(url) ||
        !url.length
      ) {
        setUrlError(true);
        return null;
      } else {
        urlTypeArray.push(urlType);
        urlArray.push(url);
        var urlObj: any = {};
        urlObj[urlType] = url;
        projectLinks = [...projectLinks, urlObj];
      }
    });
    if (!urlError && projectLinks.length) {
      console.log(projectLinks);
      // Action for URL submit to API
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  };
  const handleAddLink = () => {
    setCount((prev) => (prev < linkOptions.length ? prev + 1 : prev));
  };
  const handleRemoveLink = () => {
    setCount((prev) => (prev > 1 ? prev - 1 : prev));
  };
  return (
    <MainLayout>
      <form className="flex flex-col" onSubmit={submit}>
        {[...Array(count)].map((link, index) => (
          <LinkField
            key={index}
            index={index}
            handleAddLink={handleAddLink}
            handleRemoveLink={handleRemoveLink}
          />
        ))}
        <button
          className={`btn ${urlError ? "btn-disabled" : "btn-active"} mt-8`}
        >
          Button
        </button>
        {urlError ? (
          <div
            className="toast cursor-pointer"
            onClick={() => setUrlError(false)}
          >
            <div className="alert alert-error">
              <span>Duplicate URL Type or URL or URL is Empty.</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </form>
    </MainLayout>
  );
}

function LinkField({
  handleAddLink,
  handleRemoveLink,
  index
}: {
  handleAddLink: () => void;
  handleRemoveLink: () => void;
  index: number;
}) {
  return (
    <div className="mt-1 mb-1">
      <div className="flex justify-between">
        <select name="urlType" className="select select-primary">
          {linkOptions.map((option, index) => (
            <option key={index} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="url"
          placeholder="example.com"
          className="input input-bordered ml-1 mr-1"
        />
        <button
          className={`btn ${
            index === linkOptions.length - 1 ? "btn-disabled" : ""
          } ml-1 mr-1`}
          onClick={handleAddLink}
          type="button"
        >
          Add
        </button>
        <button
          className={`btn ${index === 0 ? "btn-disabled" : ""} ml-1 mr-1`}
          onClick={handleRemoveLink}
          // type="button"
        >
          Remove
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```